# Get a match string in (.*) with NSRegularExpression

Tags: swift, nsregularexpression

I'm using Swift 2, and trying to get a number from a HTML data response from URL, dataString is my HTML text, I use NSRegularExpression and try to get string

```
let patten = "<span class=bld>(.*)USD</span>"
let reg = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: patten, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
let rangeMatch = reg?.firstMatchInString(dataString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, dataString.characters.count))
if rangeMatch != nil {
    let res = (dataString as! NSString).substringWithRange((rangeMatch?.range)!)
    print(res)
 }
```

But the result I got is full string `<span class=bld>22309 USD</span>`, I'm only want to get `22309` number. Anyone could show me how to get it please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captured groups are located at range index 1+ of the `NSTextCheckingResult` object.

```
...rangeMatch?.rangeAtIndex(1)
```

I recommend a more specific pattern:

```
let pattern = "<span class=bld>(\\d+)\\sUSD</span>"
```

or still shorter

```
let pattern = "(\\d+)\\sUSD"
```

`\\d+` is one or more digits, `\\s` is a whitespace character